# Undefined after using addEventListener

Tags: javascript

I am very new to Javascript and am trying to translate a game i made in python into javascript. I am currently trying to get keyboard input for the game. Whenever i run this however it gives me the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined(at line 4 in this example)

Board is a 2d array used to store the board and i have tested that before the addEventListener statement Board is not undefined.

Why is this error happening and what should i do to fix it. As mentioned before i am a complete beginner at javascript so simple explanations would be greatly appreciated.
Kind regards

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
   if(event.keyCode == 65){
      console.log(Board)
      Board[this.block1[0]][this.block1[1]]=null;
      Board[this.block2[0]][this.block2[1]]=null;
      Board[this.block3[0]][this.block3[1]]=null;
      Board[this.block4[0]][this.block4[1]]=null;
```

Comment: Can you post a whole class? Because you use variables that we can't see

Comment: You should check if `this.block1` is undefined.

Comment: It's telling you `this.block1` is undefined (or `this.block2`, `this.block3`, or `this.block4`). Likely because `this` is not what you think it is due to the function being an event handler.

Comment: Th error is most likely caused by trying to access `this.block1[0]` when `this.block1` is `undefined`. The reason is that `this` probably isn't pointing at the thing you think it it. Using `this` can be tricky. `this` is probably pointing to `document`.

Comment: I've just checked and it tuns out that this.block1 was in fact undefined.

Comment: blazej how would I do that as stack overflow has a character limit?

Comment: You can edit your question at any time. There's a bunch of links directly below it. Post only relevant code, that should easily fit the limit.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`this` in your code is not what you expect it to be. If `block1` etc are local variables, reference them without `this.`. If they are members of your encapsulating object, change your callback function to use arrow syntax to let `this` reference your object: `document.addEventListener('keydown', event => { /*...*/ })`